# Check if class is inside a class - Python

Tags: python, class, tree, parent

I'd like to know if a class is located inside a class.

For instance:

```
class Example:
    class InsideExample:
        pass
```

I'd like to check if `InsideExample` is inside `Example`. How would I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can see, that `InsideExample` is inside `Example`. What do you want to check?

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: @Daniel [Already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879319/check-if-class-is-inside-a-class-python/52879365?noredirect=1#comment92672181_52879319)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what input you have and what you want to test? Do you have both `Example` and `InsideExample` as input? Or only `InsideExample`? Or the whole file? Or something else? Do you want to test whether `InsideExample` is defined inside another class, or specifically defined inside `Example`, or something else?

Comment: @user2357112 I want to check if it is inside another class.

Comment: @Aimarekin: That is 1) really vague, and 2) not what the answer you accepted does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasattr` with `isinstance` to check that the attribute is a `class`:

```
class Example:
  class InsideExample:
    pass

if hasattr(Example, 'InsideExample') and isinstance(Example.InsideExample, type):
  pass
```

Comment: What is the `isinstance` for? Why would I need it there, how does it exactly help?

Comment: @Aimarekin Unless you want to check if *any* attribute with name `InsideExample` is bound to `Example`, you have to use `isinstance` to check the type of `Example.InsideExample` to determine if it is a `class`.

Comment: I downvoted because it's a questionably-appropriate answer to a vague question, unlikely to do the right thing for anyone else who comes here trying to determine whether a class is defined inside another, and quite likely not even the right thing for the questioner.